# Xamarin Main Nib File

Tags: ios, xamarin, nib

I’m looking into the possibility of porting an older app that we maintain to Xamarin to get a shared code base between our iOS and Android versions.

Unfortunately I’ve run into a bit of an issue with porting the iOS app. I’ve fiddled around with different approaches to solving this to get the app to launch with a nib file as the main entry point (since that’s what our current app does, it’s old). No matter what I do it always seems to crash or come up black.

Here’s an outline of my attempt:

1. Create new Cross Platform - Single View App, Give it a name (e.g. Sample)
2. Remove Main.storyboard and ViewController.cs
3. Expand Sample.iOS, right click and add New File > iOS > View Controller, Give it a name (e.g. MainNib)
4. Open Info.plist, change Main Interface to MainNib for both iPhone/iPod and iPad deployments
5. Save and run > comes up black
6. Open Info.plist, go to source editor and remove the main storyboard properties, add “Main nib file name” and “Main nib file name (iPad)” entries with value “MainNib”
7. Save and run > crashes complaining about key-value compliance on property named view

Comment: What is the actual stack trace?

Comment: Here's the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/raw/k5J1Xah5

Comment: Here's the project itself if you cared to try it out: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4706564/Sample.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went digging through some code examples on github and found an adequate solution. Whatever Xamarin is doing behind the scenes to boot up the main Window doesn't seem to be compatible with setting a main nib in the Info.plist file. As an example, the [AQTapDemo project](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples) solves this problem by manually loading a view controller in the AppDelegate instead of relying on auto loading from Info.plist properties.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you look at your state trace, you will see that the ObjC exception is thrown as it is trying to make an outlet connection:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x008dea14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0890ce02 objc_exception_throw + 50
2   CoreFoundation                      0x008de631 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Foundation                          0x00f371bc -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
4   Foundation                          0x00e9183a _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115
5   Foundation                          0x00e917bf -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 295
6   Foundation                          0x00ec601d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 384
7   UIKit                               0x03639cb4 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 132
```

Looking at your `.xib`, there is a connection defined, but you do not have a matching definition in C# (and the generated `.h`), so commenting it out will allow the `.xib` to be parsed corrected at runtime:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="9532" systemVersion="15D21" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="9530"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="MainNib">
<!-- 
            <connections>
                <outlet property="view" destination="2" id="RRd-Eg-VrN"/>
            </connections>
 -->
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="2">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

There isn't anything in the `.xib` other than a UIView with two attribute settings.

Comment: Very confusing results:
1. Commenting out the connection as you've demonstrated does allow the app to run, but the screen appears black.
2. When I try adding a button (and giving it a name) to the view, Xamarin correctly generates an outlet to the MainNib.designer.cs file, but fails to run complaining about a similar key-value complaince issue for the button even though it is should be managed by the designer.cs file

Comment: I see this all the time in XCode when creating a new nib file there is always a view outlet that needs to be connected (or it will throw the same exception I'm seeing in Xamarin), I'm surprised that Xamarin isn't generating an Outlet for the view property. I've also tried (to no effect) manually adding an outlet for it in MainNib.cs. I'm not very strong with C# yet, but assuming since it is a partial class shared with the designer.cs the framework will pick up on outlets declared in MainNib.cs as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `MainNib` has component(s) which are used in code but missed connections with properties.

**Possible Solution:**
* Right click `MainNib` file -> `Open With` -> `Xcode Interface Builder`. 
*`Xcode` will open with that `.xib` file.* 
* Select `File's Owner` under `Placeholders` in `Document Outline` (in-between *ProjectNavigator* and *Storyboard Canvas*). 
* Click *Connections Inspector* on the right side of the `Xcode`.
* Check if all view components, which you will manipulate from code, are connected with their corresponding properties.
* Fix connections, or create properties if you need to.
* Save changes and close xcode.
* Refresh your `Xamarin` project or reopen the project and run.

hope that will fix the crash.